# Calculate the amount of time to complete an operation as function of time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1 operation is complexed out of N other 'small' operations, each time I complete a small operation, the time it requires for me to complete the next one, reduces by X.

How can I calculate the time required for the whole operation?

For example, I want to mine bitcoin, each time I am successfull in mining I buy more mining equipment with the money,so the next mining will be faster and so on, until i reach a certain amount of money.

How can I approach this kind of problem?

Comment: A start: If $T$ is the time to do the first small operation, then the time for the second is $T-X$, for the third is $T-2X$, and so on up to $T-(N-1)X$. You will be summing an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_i,\ i=1...N$ represents the time to complete the $i$'th small operation.
You have that $T_{i+1} = T_{i}-X$ and the first operation has a fixed cost $T_1 = const$.
Also the total time to complete the whole operation is $\sum_{i=1}^N T_i$

Now first we try to solve the recurrence relation for the $T_i$. Expanding some term we find :
$$
T_1 = cst \\
T_2 = cst -X \\
T_3 = cst -X -X \\
...
$$
We conclude that $T_i = T_1 -(i-1)X$. Now we can compute the whole time :
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N T_i = \sum_{i=1}^N \left[T_1 -(i-1)X \right] = \sum_{i=1}^N T_1 - X\sum_{i=1}^N (i-1) = N\ T_1 -X\ \frac{N(N-1)}{2}
$$

Comment: X ( the time difference between the operation is not constant). the amount of time it takes for the first operation is 1/n/m+n where n is my "power" m is the other players "power". so every time i complete a small operation i add to the global power as well.